# Connect to SoundCloud API with Facebook account

Tags: soundcloud

Using the SoundCloud API to show the logging in screen with the following URL:

```
https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=[my_client_id]&redirect_uri=[my_redirect_url]&display=popup&response_type=code&scope=non-expiring
```

When clicking on the Sign in with Facebook button, I get the Facebook screen and enter the details.
When returning, I get the following URL:

```
https://soundcloud.com/connect/via/facebook/returning?code=[returned_code]&state=[returned_state]
```

Using the returned code as from the URL above to get the token, via url (https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token) with payload

```
{
client_id=[my_client_id],
client_secret=[my_client_secret],
grant_type=authorization_code, 
redirect_uri=[my_redirect_url],
code=[code_as_returned_above]
}
```

I get a 401 (Unauthorized) error.

Am I doing something wrong using facebook for signin in?

Note, this method works perfectly when using SoundCloud credentials in the sign in page.

Comment: this is a error on soundcloud' side. you probably can't do anything about it.

Comment: Still nothing? I presume that this is not going to get fixed from SoundCloud side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No response from SoundCloud to provide a solution.